# "within a few years." vs "within few years."

Tags: grammar

Which of the following sentences is right?

> "This problem will be solved **within a few years**."

OR

> "This problem will be solved **within few years**."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new here too.

In ''Grammar in use'' of Cambridge Press University, it says that:

- Few: Not many
- A few: Some, a small enough

So, please compare these examples:

- She's lucky. She got few problems.
  (**not many problems**)
- She felt on edge. She got a few problems.
  (**some problems**)

So in your question:

- "This problem will be solved within a few years."
  (**some years**)
- "This problem will be solved within few years."
  (**Not many years**)

In my opinion, Both are Okay, It depends on your case. So feel free to choose it if you find it suitable for your situation.